# Chrome cookie values are not stored

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

i wanted to browse my cookies, so i went into %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default and took the file Cookies. I opened it with Sqlite database browser, but the cookies have no value. Wasn't there supposed to be the content of the cookie in there too?

[image]

Is the content protected? Or is it stored somewhere else?

Comment: do you see a `encrypted_value` field with every record having `(BLOB)`? [5 months ago, all cookies were encrypted](https://codereview.chromium.org/24734007) as you can see in the Chromium 'Issue'. This has been updated to all current versions of Chrome AFAIK. If you see the `(BLOB)`s then that means you're in the right place, but it is encrypted. Someone at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496209/cookie-issue-with-chrome-33-beta) has apparently found a way to decrypt this, but I haven't tested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it stored somewhere else?

If you see a `encrypted_value` field with every record having `(BLOB)`, then you are in the correct place:

[image]

---

> ... and blob is encrypted data itself

<sub><sub>via [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/19cca567e118fef3111f5a2e8c6b28adb3c3543e/chrome/browser/sync/protocol/encryption.proto)</sub></sub>

---

> Is the content protected?

5 months ago, all Google Chrome started to encrypt all cookies. They started with doing this in Chromium (as you can see in [this](https://codereview.chromium.org/24734007) Chromium 'Issue').

AFAIK, this has now been updated to all current versions of Chrome. If you see the `(BLOB)s` then that means you're in the right place, but the cookies are encrypted.

---

[Over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496209/cookie-issue-with-chrome-33-beta), someone has 'found' a way to decrypt this, but when I attempted it, it didn't work (although my programming skills are somewhat limited - so you could have a try yourself...)

If you want to see / delete the cookies stored by Google Chrome, go to `chrome://settings/cookies` (or Settings > Show advanced settings > Content settings > All cookies and site data) and you can delete them from there.